# What version of Edge marked the start of using Chromium internally?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm looking for info about what the first major version of Edge was, that used Chromium? What does the useragent string look like between the two versions/how did the UA change? Was it purely a version number change, or did some other element of it change too?

I have to educate some people as to how to recognize "Chromium based Edge" versus "non-Chromium based Edge" from the user agent string alone.. At the moment I believe the indicator for this is the UA string referring to windows/mac as well as `Edg/` rather than the full word, apparently a [by design](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/user-agent-string) behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User agent strings do not identify early versions of Microsoft Edge,
since the Microsoft developers at the beginning left the Chrome
user agent string as-is.

In Edge version 12, they adopted the `Edge/` string and the
first one was:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240`
([source](https://lafibre.info/navigateurs/user-agent/)).
This version was also called
[EdgeHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdgeHTML)
and was not based on Chromium.

For the real Chromium-based Edge,
they moved to `edg/` in version 75, and this became:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3739.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/75.0.109.0`
([source](https://udger.com/resources/ua-list/browser-detail?browser=Microsoft%20Edge)).

You can read about the history of the Edge browser and all its versions in
[Wikipedia Microsoft Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge).

For comparison, here are some user agent strings from a
[Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56361977/165358)
from May 2019.

**The Chrome browser userAgent:**

> mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml,
>   like gecko) chrome/74.0.3729.169 safari/537.36

**The Edge browser userAgent:**

> mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml,
>   like gecko) chrome/64.0.3282.140 safari/537.36 **edge**/18.17763

**The Microsoft Chromium Edge Dev userAgent:**

> mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml,
>   like gecko) chrome/76.0.3800.0 safari/537.36 **edg**/76.0.167.1

**The Microsoft Chromium Edge Canary userAgent:**

> mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml,
>   like gecko) chrome/76.0.3800.0 safari/537.36 **edg**/76.0.167.1

Comment: It appears the first version is Chromium Edge 75, depends if we’re talking, development or stable though